# Coldfusion 10 throwing Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, socketexception, coldfusion-10

We recently upgraded two of our ColdFusion 9 servers to ColdFusion 10 servers and now I get the error "Software caused connection abort: socket write error" 10-20 times per day, on the cfcontent tag when serving up pdfs.

I read this entry: [Connection reset by peer: socket write error - cfcontent on Coldfusion 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141659/connection-reset-by-peer-socket-write-error-cfcontent-on-coldfusion-10) and it appears to be the exact same issue. I read the answers but it is NOT a user issue hitting stop on their browser or something. Both applications were working perfectly under ColdFusion 9 and now both are throwing the error.

Does anyone know of a Tomcat setting that could be causing this issue?  Once again it is not a software issue it is a server issue with the new ColdFusion 10 server. Is anyone else having this issue and have you got it resolved? Thanks.

Comment: Does it happen for all PDFs or only some PDFs, or does the same PDF sometimes work and sometimes not?

Comment: I think that the other question you referenced gives a pretty good explanation of the issue; ColdFusion is attempting to return the output buffer but the client is no longer listening.  Have you traced back those 10-20 requests to see if they were bots?  The is not really a ColdFusion 10 "issue", it is just that the new version is reporting the error when ColdFusion 9 did not.

Comment: @Peter - It happens at random. I have repeated it but not consistently. Also it does not happen on my local so it has to be the communication between IIS and Tomcat

Comment: @Miguel - I would say that a server kicking 10+ errors per day is in fact an issue. If it is reporting the error then how do I shut that off? It is getting to where I may have to go back to Coldfusion 9.  It is not a bot as I can recreate it if I click on enough pdfs and have had complaints from users.

Comment: I was not implying that this is not an issue for you, just that ColdFusion 10 is now logging it where it was not in previous versions.

Comment: My clients (not bots) are getting this error. Not consistently but often enough to have shaken client trust. One client got it 3 times in a row in the span of 2 minutes. Half hour later trying to replicate the error, I can open the file.