# How to detect if a script is running via a scheduled task

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks, railo, cfml

Is there a way to detect if a script is runned by a scheduled task.

I have a script which gives throws a `ClientAbortException` because I am using `cfflush`.
I need to detect if the script is running via a scheduled task so the script can run successfully.

Comment: this is a duplicate qustion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977831/how-do-i-determine-if-a-scheduled-task-was-ran-automatically-or-ran-in-a-browser/13978558#13978558

Comment: Here's something to look at regarding the error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141659/connection-reset-by-peer-socket-write-error-cfcontent-on-coldfusion-10.  Seems odd, as it seems to imply that the task scheduler is terminating the connection to the server after the request is made but before it is complete.

Comment: And you might also consider using cgi.remote_addr to determine if it is a scheduled task.  It contains the IP address of the remote host making the request.  For a scheduled task, it will be the IP address of your server.

Comment: @barry The drawback here is when you have multiple instances of your app deployed over multiple server, you need to configure the IP-address somewhere to check if the CGI.REMOTE_ADDR is equal. 
BTW, i found a bugreport regarding the error: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO-727

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you can check it via CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT:

```
<cfif CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT NEQ "CFSCHEDULE">
  <cfflush>
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate question as Travis said, but another answer is you could add a url parameter to the scheduled task something like ?auto= which would allow you to check the url scope to determine how it was ran.

Comment: that would also allow you to bypass the cfflush in the browser if you wanted to.